# I am not able to open Ubuntu while I switch on my laptop

Tags: boot, grub2

I am not able to open the system. Kindly check the image showing when the system gets on:

[image: GRUB menu]

Comment: I don't see any problem in the image. What's wrong? Please post each error message that you see.

Comment: Did you try to press "up-arrow" 4 times to mark the Ubuntu line, and then press enter ?

Comment: Does anything happen when you select the Ubuntu entry in the boot menu with the arrow keys and press Enter?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have another problem you have not included in your post, it should be quite easy.  Just press the up arrow key four times, or until it reaches the  "Ubuntu" line, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or right arrow key, or possibly the space key, to boot.